# How to bring subview of uiviewcontroller's custom view created through xib to front?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, swift2, xib

I have created UIViewcontroller's custom view via xib file and assign view custom class in storyboard. In custom view I have few subview which shown on some action. I have added also subview in controller's view in storyboard. Now if I bring these controller's subview via this line of code

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(vSubview)
```

But problem come when I want to bring subview to front that was added in custom view added via xib. I have tried following possible way

```
 self.view.bringSubviewToFront(sideView)
 sideView.layer.zPosition = 2
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.bringSubviewToFront(sideView)
```

but in vain. I have confirmed it that subview I want to bring to front is present in view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Set the tag to subView. Try to get the subview with its tag from superView. Or put a loop on all subviews in `self.view` until you get the subView with its tag. Then bring that to front `bringSubviewToFront`. *Make sure you added the sideView(your subview) in `self.view`*